# Connect surfaces

Tags: edit-mode, faces

How can I extend two surfaces so they connect.

thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the edge of one of the two plane you want to extend:
[image]

Press <kbd>G</kbd> two times (to activate sliding), and then <kbd>C</kbd> to extend sliding beyond the object shape. You will see this:
[image]

Now if you move the mouse you will be able to slide the edge mantaining it on the face direction. Slide it beyond the limit you want to reach (beyond the purple line in your image):
[image]
and left click to confirm.

Then do the same with the edge of the other plane:
[image]

Now deselect all with <kbd>A</kbd> and select all the vertices of one of the two planes (put the mouse near a vertex and press <kbd>L</kbd>), press spacebar and write "knife", on the dropdown menu you'll see, press the "Intersect (knife)" option. You will see an edge on the intersection of the two planes:
[image]

Now select the two excess edges (you don't need them anymore) and delete them:
[image]

Now you see one corner edge but you have two in the same place, so select all with <kbd>A</kbd> and find "Remove doubles" command (you find a button in the left panel or you can use spacebar and start typing "Remove doubles" until you see it in the dropdown menu).

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD1:**
Select both the edges and press **F key** to join them by creating a new face
*or* 
**METHOD2:**
Select the vertices/or edges you want to merge then press **ALT + M** and hit on any one of the options see there.

Comment: I think he want to join them to the purple line. The merge option will merge them in different points but not on that line. The face will not merge them.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the vertex selection mode and select the two vertices that you want to join

[image]

Press S + 0 to join them and press ENTER to confirm

[image]

Repeat with the bottom vertices

[image]

Now select the entire mesh with A, press space and type "remove doubles" and press ENTER to confirm

[image]

The vertices that were superimposed will be removed if they become only one.

[image]

**And ready!**